# AWS Elastic Beanstalk php take over 128ms on empty php file is this normal?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

we are deploying  a PHP script on AWS elastic beanstalk and found it's take a lot of time compare with normal servers 
even on empty PHP files with no code to run it's take about 128 ms form google chrome TTFB

[google chrome ttfb screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpXkm.jpg)

is this normal? and if not normal why ? and what to do to make it faster

my environment config is :

```
Environment type: Load balanced, auto scaling
Number instances: 2 - 4
Scale based on Average network out
Add instance when > 6000000
Remove instance when < 2000000
Instance type: t2.micro
Root volume type: Magnetic
Root volume size: 10 GiB
Availability Zones: Any
```

---

and .elasticbeanstalk contents is :
config.yml

```
branch-defaults:
  default:
    environment: Development
global:
  application_name: testing
  default_ec2_keyname: testing
  default_platform: 64bit Amazon Linux 2016.03 v2.1.4 running PHP 5.6
  default_region: eu-central-1
  profile: eb-cli
  sc: null
```

Comment: I think it's normal. You've got the overhead of the load balancer, PHP container (web server?) and the fact that the code is ran on a virtual server. You may optimize some bits of it (e.g. change webserver or use PHP-FPM if you're not doing that already) but overall don't expect any miracles.

Comment: thanks for reply i not installed any thing on server i am looking for imporve this speed first and about PHP-FPM is it will imporve the cpu time ? thank you

Comment: If you have apache and do the recommended thing to use a pre-fork MPM then switching to PHP-FPM and a threaded MPM will improve performance. If not then I don't know.